# How to modify javascript file in foundation-rails gem on server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I've discovered that there are a few issues with the foundation.tooltip.js file in the foundation-rails gem version-5.5.3.2:

1. If you have over 50 tooltips on the page the page becomes unresponsive for a while. The solution is to modify the .js file as instructed here: [Tooltip Issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/6944#issuecomment-154242356).
2. There is a security issue with the same js file as mentioned here: [Security issue](https://vuldb.com/?id.93865).

Is there a more elegant way of patching the js file other than editing the file in the gem installed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

That version is at EOL so the best way would be to submit a pull request that adds that solution the file and then wait for someone to accept and merge.

That's the the most elegant solution a part from using a seperate plugin for tooltips.

Comment: Wouldn't a pull request only affect the latest version of the gem? I need to use the version 5.5.3.2 specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can fork specific version and fix for your own requirement. and change gem path to your git repository.

Comment: I tried that, however, when trying to deploy I get an error "ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Name expected (line: 17864, col: 111, pos: 559646)" during the Execute assets:precompile step in Capistrano. Just forking the project without changing anything causes this error. Any ideas?